# Parse xml with xpath for jaxb

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jaxb

I want to use `ArrayList` with url from xml:

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:mailru="https://news.mail.ru/">
    <channel>
      <item>
         <enclosure url="https://news.mail.ru/pic/a7/a4/main24128764_eb1fd077a98a69823f0661e5ccb4b505.jpg#620#388" type="image/jpeg" />
```

I use this:

```
@XmlPath("channel/item/enclosure/[@url]/text()")
private ArrayList <String> urls;
```

but it is not work. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct xpath is

```
channel/item/enclosure/@url
```

will give you the value of the url attribute of the node enclosure